# How do i access an input value that is up one level, and then a sibling of, using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a page that contains numerous divs like what is shown below, it is a page of color swatches, ie thumb size images. what i have to do is this: when the user mouses over an image swatch, it has to display the value of the input field who's name is 'descriptive name'. 
the difficulty i'm having is accessing that input field's value. the image is nested in a label. the label and the input field are siblings.,

my pseudo code is something like this:

```
$('label.color-options img').each(function(){
$(this).mouseover(function(){
    var descriptiveName = $(this).upOneLevel().sibling().('input.swatch-    desciptive-name').value);
    $('#display-descriptive-name').html(descriptiveName);
}) })
```

the page mark up is this:

```
<div id="display-name"> </div>
<!-- END MAIN PRODUCT IMAGE -->
<!-- the page is full of these color swatches -->
<div class="color-swatch-wrapper">
<input type="hidden" value="Avacado 77" name="descriptive-name" class="swatch-descriptive-name" /> 
<input type="radio" name="id[10]" value="129" id="attrib-10-129" class="color-swatch-radio-btn" />
<label class="attribsRadioButton color-options" for="attrib-10-129">
    PP77<br />
    <img src="images/attributes/artichoke_green.jpg" alt="" width="260" height="320" />
</label>
</div>
```

big thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you can mix normal JS with jquery selectors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you don't need to attach your event handlers in a loop, and to get the value of an `input` element you can use `val()`.

You can use `parent().siblings()`, like this:

```
$('label.color-options img').mouseover(function(){
    var descriptiveName = $(this).parent().siblings('input.swatch-desciptive-name').val();
    $('#display-descriptive-name').html(descriptiveName);
});
```

Or alternatively, you can use `closest()` and `find()`:

```
$('label.color-options img').mouseover(function(){
    var descriptiveName = $(this).closest('.color-swatch-wrapper').find('input.swatch-desciptive-name').val();
    $('#display-descriptive-name').html(descriptiveName);
});
```

I would recommend the latter as it will not break if you change the HTML structure of those elements, so long as the class names remain.

Comment: Beat me to it, with examples!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var descriptiveName = $(this).parent().parent().find('input.swatch-descriptive-name').val();
```

Check the spelling of "descriptive" in your CSS class.